# What is the definition of quasi-transversally intersection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm considering a reduced curve $Y\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$ and a multisecant line $L$. What does it mean that $L$ intersect $Y$ quasi-transversally?